# Issue while Importing CSV data into SQLite database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, csv

I want to import a CSV file which includes two table of data: one is account_master and second is category_master into SQlite database.
My code is as below

```
public class MainActivityextends Activity
{
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_setting); 

          mButtonImport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
            if (!exportDir.exists()) {
                exportDir.mkdirs();
            }

            file = new File(exportDir, "DemoFile.csv");
              try {
                CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file));
                String [] nextLine;
                try {
                    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                        String acctitle=nextLine[1];
                        String accname=nextLine[2];
                        int value=mDatabaseConnectionAPI.addAccountData(new Account_Masters(acctitle,accname));

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    }
}
```

**Account_Masters.java**

```
import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;

public class Account_Masters implements Serializable{

@DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
int acc_id;

@DatabaseField
String acc_title;

@DatabaseField
String acc_name;

public int getAcc_id() {
    return acc_id;
}
public void setAcc_id(int acc_id) {
    this.acc_id = acc_id;
}
public Account_Masters() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Account_Masters(int accid, String acctitle, String accname) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.acc_id=accid;
    this.acc_name=accname;
    this.acc_title=acctitle;
}
public Account_Masters(String acctitle, String accname) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.acc_name=accname;
    this.acc_title=acctitle;
}

public String getAcc_title() {
    return acc_title;
}
public void setAcc_title(String acc_title) {
    this.acc_title = acc_title;
}
public String getAcc_name() {
    return acc_name;
}
public void setAcc_name(String acc_name) {
    this.acc_name = acc_name;
}
```

**Category_Master.java**

```
public class Category_Master implements Serializable{

@DatabaseField(generatedId=true)
int cat_id;

@DatabaseField
String acc_id;

@DatabaseField
String cat_name;

@DatabaseField
String cat_type;

@DatabaseField
String cat_mode;

public Category_Master() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public Category_Master(String acc_id,String cat_name,String cat_type,String cat_mode)
{
    this.acc_id=acc_id;
    this.cat_name=cat_name;
    this.cat_type=cat_type;
    this.cat_mode=cat_mode;
}



public int getCat_id() {
    return cat_id;
}
public void setCat_id(int cat_id) {
    this.cat_id = cat_id;
}
public String getCat_name() {
    return cat_name;
}

public void setCat_name(String cat_name) {
    this.cat_name = cat_name;
}

public String getCat_type() {
    return cat_type;
}

public void setCat_type(String cat_type) {
    this.cat_type = cat_type;
}

public String getCat_mode() {
    return cat_mode;
}

public void setCat_mode(String cat_mode) {
    this.cat_mode = cat_mode;
}

public String getAcc_id() {
    return acc_id;
}

public void setAcc_id(String acc_id) {
    this.acc_id = acc_id;
}

 }
```

**DatabaseConnectionAPI.java**

```
public class DatabaseConnectionAPI extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

// The Android's default system path of your application database.
// /mnt/sdcard/
private final static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/pkg.android.rootways.rootmoney/databases/";

// private final static String DB_PATH ="/mnt/sdcard/";

private final static String DB_NAME = "RootMoney.sqlite";

private final Context myContext;

public static SQLiteDatabase db;
private RuntimeExceptionDao<Account_Masters, String> personRuntimeDao=null;
private RuntimeExceptionDao<Category_Master, String> categoryRuntimeDao=null;



/**
 * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
 * access to the application assets and resources.
 * 
 * @param context
 */
public DatabaseConnectionAPI(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_PATH + DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {

        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */

private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

//  public boolean delete(String sql) {
//
//      
//      db.execSQL(sql);
//      return false;
//
//  }

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-0folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public  void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    try {
        db.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("no database connected to close");
    }
    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    System.out.println("Databse opened...." + db);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (db != null)
        db.close();
    super.close();
}
   @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0, ConnectionSource arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, ConnectionSource arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
  public RuntimeExceptionDao<Account_Masters, String> getPersonDataDao() {

    Log.v("s", "getTimeDataDao call");

    if (personRuntimeDao == null) {
        personRuntimeDao = getRuntimeExceptionDao(Account_Masters.class);
    }
    return personRuntimeDao;
}
   public int addAccountData(Account_Masters project)
{
    Log.v("Da", "addPersonData call");
            RuntimeExceptionDao<Account_Masters, String> dao =   getPersonDataDao();
    int i = dao.create(project);
    return i;
}

}
```

**My CSV file Format**

[image]

When I run the above code in my SQLite Database, it stores the values like below

[image]

I want category data to go into Category_master and Account data to go into account master.
So, has anybody an idea on how can I do that?

Comment: You will have to filter for tablenames, if you are going to have 2 tables in one csv. Id recommend using 2 seperate csv files. But if you want it to be in one File, Check if first entry is a number => valueRow, else HeaderRow. And if you have had a 2nd headerRow, your in the next table. Handle that in Code accordingly

Comment: You have to use a CSV file for each table. Since a CSV file represents 1 data table only.

Comment: @DanielBo :you have any idae how can i separator two tables in one csv file?

Comment: yes i do, i even explained the logic id use :) check first comment.

Comment: @DanielBo : ya i read but i not getting idae exetlly what you say about id for which id csv row id or header id?

Comment: if the first element of your next Line has a number at its beginning, its a row with content. If there is a Word, its a tableHeader.

Comment: @DanielBo :Ok i get point , thanks for post and ur time !!!